# Android studio: new project vs new module

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio uses the concept of `modules`, whereas other IDEs like Eclipse use `projects`.
However AS `File` menu has the option to create a `New Module` as well as a `new Project`.

What are the differences between these two if any?

Which one is recommended to use?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Structure+of+IntelliJ+IDEA+Project) (Android Studio is based on Intellij IDEA) :

> Whatever you do in IntelliJ IDEA, you do that in the context of a
>   project. A project is an organizational unit that represents a
>   complete software solution.
>
> Your finished product may be decomposed into a series of discrete,
>   isolated modules, but it's a project definition that brings them
>   together and ties them into a greater whole.

For Android, it means one project per app, and one module per library and per test app.

There are multiple issues if you try to build multiple apps within the same project. It's possible, but if you try (like I did), you will see that almost everything is designed to work with a single app per project.

For example, there is an option to "rebuild the project", which makes no sense with multiple apps, many other project settings would be useless, and the built-in VCS system isn't great when you have multiple repositories.

Comment: "It means one project per app, and one module per library and per test app"... What does this mean? If a "test app" is an app, then there can only be two modules per project, one for an app (regular or test app) and one for a library.

Comment: @LarsH, I would rephrase it as: "a project per main app"

Comment: this is not the answer. bad answer

Answer (score 176):

KISS answer:

**module** in *Android Studio* is like a **project** in *Eclipse*

**project** in *Android Studio* is like a **workspace** in *Eclipse*

Comment: I have been struggling with this issue myself and while this seems to be the conceptual case, I am confused.  When I create a new 'Project' in Android Studio I am presented with a wizard that asks me about things like Theme, use of ActionBar, Grid Layout and such.  I would have thought these things would be left to the Module.  If these questions are just so the appropriate support libs are added to the 'Project' then I understand, but I also see these same things when creating a new module.  Quite confusing.

Comment: You have a point, but the accepted answer just notes the problems with trying to work with android studio as if it was eclipse. Most people looking for this question just need to know what is the analogy.

Comment: Creating a new project in Android does not looks more like an app with manifest / res / and src  - as apposed to a "workspace".    When creating a Module, two o the types offered are 1) application module and 2) android library module.    #1 seems redundant to "new project"  and #1 and #2 seem the same.

Comment: oO is a module really that much?!

Comment: @MartinPfeffer - no, but that's the closest analogy, read more here: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/project_structure.html

Comment: after updating AS and gradle to latest, I get the "no module" message when trying to run the project, and in the "android" view (as opposed to e.g. project view), this project does no longer contain an arrow that can be tilted down, i.e. AS do not see this module anymore. Where is the module defined? Any tips how to correct the error?

Answer (score 40):

> A **project** in *Android Studio* represents a complete Android app. *Android Studio projects consist of one or more* **modules**.
>
> A **module** is a component of your app that you can build, test, or debug independently.
>
> **Modules** contain the source code and resources for your app.

Answer (score 10):

### From [updated docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-app-module.html) [2019]:

> #### Modules provide a container for your app's source code, resource
>   files, and app level settings, such as the module-level build file and
>   Android manifest file. Each module can be independently built, tested,
>   and debugged.
>
> Android Studio uses modules to make it easy to add new devices to your
>   project. By following a few simple steps in Android Studio, you can
>   create a module to contain code that's specific to a device type, such
>   as Wear OS or Android TV. Android Studio automatically creates module
>   directories, such as source and resource directories, and a default
>   build.gradle file appropriate for the device type. Also, Android
>   Studio creates device modules with recommended build configurations,
>   such as using the Leanback library for Android TV modules.

Ex:

- Phone & Tablet Module
- Android Wear Module
- Android TV Module
- Glass Module

Besides these, you can also have a "local library module". Say, you develop a Account Management Framework as a library module to be used ultimately in your App, you can do it as a separate module in the same project. To include that in your App, you would have to write something like,

```
compile project(':mylibrary')
```

Docs say,

> This declares a dependency on an Android library module named
>   "mylibrary" (this name must match the library name defined as an
>   include in your settings.gradle file). It requires the build system to
>   compile the library module with your app module and include the
>   resulting AAR file in your APK.

Lastly, [Intellij mentions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/about-modules.html) some more details about Module configuration files:

> Configuration information for a module is stored in a **.iml** module
>   file. By default, such a file is located in the module's content root
>   folder.
>
> Development teams, normally, share the `.iml` module files through
>   version control.

This `.iml` file is a bit *scary* to look at. Here is an example from my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id=":app" external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/.." external.system.id="GRADLE" external.system.module.group="LearnCity" external.system.module.version="unspecified" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android-gradle" name="Android-Gradle">
      <configuration>
        <option name="GRADLE_PROJECT_PATH" value=":app" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
    <facet type="android" name="Android">
      <configuration>
        <option name="SELECTED_BUILD_VARIANT" value="debug" />
        <option name="ASSEMBLE_TASK_NAME" value="assembleDebug" />
        <option name="COMPILE_JAVA_TASK_NAME" value="compileDebugSources" />
        <afterSyncTasks>
          <task>generateDebugSources</task>
        </afterSyncTasks>
        <option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" />
        <option name="MANIFEST_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" />
        <option name="RES_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver3/layout" />
        <option name="RES_FOLDERS_RELATIVE_PATH" value="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver3/layout;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver3;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver2/layout;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver2;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver1/layout;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver1;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver0/layout;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver0;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/learner/layout;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/tutor/layout;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/obsolete/layout;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/learner;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/tutor;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/obsolete;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res;file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/res" />
        <option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_7" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/classes/debug" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/classes/test/debug" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/source/r/debug" isTestSource="false" generated="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/source/aidl/debug" isTestSource="false" generated="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug" isTestSource="false" generated="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/source/rs/debug" isTestSource="false" generated="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/source/apt/debug" isTestSource="false" generated="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/res/google-services/debug" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/res/rs/debug" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/res/resValues/debug" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/source/r/androidTest/debug" isTestSource="true" generated="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/source/aidl/androidTest/debug" isTestSource="true" generated="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/source/buildConfig/androidTest/debug" isTestSource="true" generated="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/source/rs/androidTest/debug" isTestSource="true" generated="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/source/apt/androidTest/debug" isTestSource="true" generated="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/res/rs/androidTest/debug" type="java-test-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/generated/res/resValues/androidTest/debug" type="java-test-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/res" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/assets" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/aidl" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/rs" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/shaders" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/testDebug/res" type="java-test-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/testDebug/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/testDebug/assets" type="java-test-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/testDebug/aidl" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/testDebug/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/testDebug/rs" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/testDebug/shaders" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver3/layout" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver3" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver2/layout" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver2" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver1/layout" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver1" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver0/layout" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout/ver0" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common/layout" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/learner/layout" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/tutor/layout" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/obsolete/layout" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/common" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/learner" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/tutor" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts/obsolete" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/layouts" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/assets" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/aidl" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/rs" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/shaders" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/androidTest/res" type="java-test-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/androidTest/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/androidTest/assets" type="java-test-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/androidTest/aidl" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/androidTest/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/androidTest/rs" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/androidTest/shaders" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/res" type="java-test-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/assets" type="java-test-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/aidl" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/rs" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/shaders" isTestSource="true" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/assets" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/blame" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/builds" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/classes" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/incremental" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/incremental-classes" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/incremental-runtime-classes" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/incremental-safeguard" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/instant-run-resources" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/instant-run-support" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/jniLibs" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/manifests" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/multi-dex" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/pre-dexed" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/reload-dex" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/res" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/restart-dex" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/rs" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/shaders" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/split-apk" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/symbols" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/transforms" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/outputs" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/tmp" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 25 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="google-http-client-android-1.22.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="firebase-analytics-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="firebase-core-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="play-services-auth-base-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="gson-2.8.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="play-services-tasks-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="constraint-layout-1.0.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.50" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="design-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="android-job-1.1.8" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="transition-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="play-services-base-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="multispinner-0.1.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="play-services-auth-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-core-ui-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="simpleratingbar-0.1.5" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="play-services-maps-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="play-services-location-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="firebase-iid-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-core-utils-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="jsr305-2.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-fragment-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="TEST" name="multidex-instrumentation-1.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="constraint-layout-solver-1.0.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="androidannotations-api-3.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="java-uuid-generator-3.1.4" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="google-http-client-1.22.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="firebase-messaging-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="firebase-analytics-impl-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="firebase-common-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="eventbus-3.0.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="cat-1.0.5" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="play-services-basement-10.2.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-compat-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-v4-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="multidex-1.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="TEST" name="hamcrest-core-1.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-media-compat-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="TEST" name="junit-4.12" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="recyclerview-v7-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="appcompat-v7-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="animated-vector-drawable-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-annotations-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-vector-drawable-25.3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="backend" exported="" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="android-android-25" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: While the accepted answer was dead-on, time and Google's tendency to change like the wind has rendered it obsolete (dare I say, `@Deprecated`?).  This makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA creates a project for the entire code base you work with, and a module for each of its individual components. So, IntelliJ IDEA module is more like an Eclipse project, and project is roughly similar to Eclipse workspace. There's no exact equivalent to Eclipse's workspace that contains all your work, but you can open multiple projects in multiple frames at the same time.

Here is the IntelliJ IDEA Q&A for Eclipse Users page-

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html

Answer (score 1):

Modules are like apkLibs ie it has its own res, manifest, tests etc but the main app usually uses various apklibs/modules to help put it all together in one solution

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio structure**

```
Project <- Module <- Configuration
```

`Project` consolidates single or multiple modules, were module can have none, one or multiple configurations(Application, Test...)

`Module` is used to group, reuse, build time purpose. It can be created for application or for library/framework

Single Project allows you to manage all cases which you can run into in scope of the same business project. For example you are developing some SDK, that is why you should have SDK module, also you should provide consumers by Demo Application(each for Java and Kotlin languages), that  is why you create application module which includes your SDK, then you decide to modularise your SDK and create separate modules with dependencies between them.

[[Xcode structure]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215808/4770877)
[[Swift module]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67130959/4770877)

Answer (score -5):

Referring to @Oded Breiner answer I would say that:

**module** in *Android Studio* is like a **project** in *Eclipse*

**project** in *Android Studio* is like a **working set** in *Eclipse*

Comment: Not really. IMHO "working sets" in Eclipse are just "filters" for the current workspace. You can't have two workspaces in Eclipse, as well as you can't have two projects opened in the same instance of Android Studio (in fact when you open another project, you have to replace the former, or to open the latter in a new window)

Comment: You could suggest edit instead referring original answer with little changes!