# Centralize src/main directory in Android Studio using Gradle?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-library, android-productflavors

I would like to bring in the src directory **main** in my projects as a Library or dependency.

Using Android Studio/Gradle Flavor setup, it's possible to have multi-app setup with flavors:

```
app/
  src/
    flavor1/
    flavor2/
    main/
```

main carrying the base code of all flavors in the project.

I would like to centralize my main code across multiple projects

One way I envision, is to bring the 
**main** directory in via [git-clone-task](https://github.com/palominolabs/gradle-git-clone-task)
or
[gradle-git](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git)

But that would limit the scope to my team only.

Is there is a way or understanding behind centralizing the retrieval and placement
of a src directory in Android Studio Projects using Gradle, then I could make the project public without all the ssh/auth stuff needed with the git-clone way.

I really want to bring in the **main** dir like....

```
  compile 'com.awesomeprojects.src.main:1.0'
```

What are some options for this use case?

Comment: What about using modules? Maybe take a look at here is worthing http://stackoverflow.com/a/17187867/1568429

Comment: The standard solution is to turn the main code into a separate Java or Android library, shared as a Jar or AAR archive.

Comment: Then how/where do i designate that lib as the main src dir?

Comment: I'm missing something fundamental... I use dependencies all the time. It definitely does seem like what I want is to construct a library/SDK. So basically all the "new" code would just reference that lib, like I ref other libs...so basically it doesn't have to be the main src dir? hmmmm #progress