# Convert Eclipse Workspace to Android Studio Project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have an Eclipse workspace with some Android projects, some are library projects others are Android application projects that depends on these libraries.

For example I have `Lib1 Lib2  Lib3` as libraries and `App1 App2` ad application.
`App1`  needs `Lib1` and `Lib3`, `App2` need `Lib1 Lib2 Lib3`.

I would like to migrate to Android Studio. I already have a gradle build script for each project, and I already use gradle to build the apks.

How can I convert  the Eclipse workspace to one or more Android Studio projects?

From what I read here [Project vs Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187080/android-studio-new-project-vs-new-module) is not a good practice to have multiple app in one Android Studio project, but you can have multiple library modules in one   project. So I guess I have to create one module for each App and import the libraries multiple times, one time for each project. And have something like this:

```
App1
  Lib1
  Lib3

App3
  Lib1
  Lib2
  Lib3
```

Answer (score -2):

Android studio's "import project" works quite well. Just select the Eclipse project file to import and Android Studio will detect the libraries necessary. It will also ask you if you want to turn the libraries into dependencies.

Essentially, Android Studio does all the work for you.

You will also get a text file giving a detailed description of how Android Studio changed the file structure and which files it added or did not use.

And yes, import each app into a separate android project.