# How to manage Android Studio code in a structured way

Tags: android-studio, code-structure

just want to ask is there any tutorial on how to structure Android Studio coding? i'm new in Android Studio, looking for some best practice to manage our code. Thanks so much.

Comment: structure way??? in the sense?, i didn't get you.@sunny

Comment: @NarendraBaratam because it is easily to messed up when you have a lot of activities, layouts, fragments and etc, even myself get blurred when i looked back the coding ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Concerning the impact of the gradle build tool on the organisation of your project, you could use this link: [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide). It is not strictly speaking a tutorial but it's easy to read.
2. Concerning the overall organisation of an Android studio project, and in particular the use of one or several modules in your project, maybe [Android studio: new project vs new module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187080/android-studio-new-project-vs-new-module) can help you.

Comment: alright thanks so much, will look at it in a while :D