# Permitting users expand the app

Tags: android, jar, module, libraries, aar

I want to create an app which can be expanded by `modules` (or something else) by the users, allowing them to download only parts they need to use.

I think it can be done with `.aar` files but I'm not sure. May be there are better solutions. I would be grateful if you can give me advice about this, and more if you can show me a tutorial about how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following links will help you to understand and then implement your own module/library for android.

[Android's documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html)

[Vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html)

[CodeTut's tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-and-publishing-an-android-library--cms-24582)

[A stackoverflow question over project vs module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187080/android-studio-new-project-vs-new-module)

If you are new into these, you will probably stumble. Take some more help from here, github, google and MOST IMPORTANTLY, youtube. check out some videos.

Hope it helps... Cheers!